# How to register callback function from C to Python using embedding python

Tags: python-2.7, google-cloud-platform, python-embedding

I want to register my callback function(written in c) to python code from c/c++. How can i do that? can you please help me?

**pythoncode.py**

```
def receive_messages(arg, callbackfunc):
     event.eventfunction(callback=callbackfunc)
```

---

**sample.c**

```
void my_callback( char *msg)
{
   printf("inside my_callback: %s\n", msg);
}

register_callback_fun(my_callback)
{
  //import modules snippet
  ??
}
```